# dialog flow skipping a parameter based on another parameter

Tags: facebook, chatbot, dialogflow-es

I created an intent for my item selling store with name "Order". I want to ask user if he wants the item to be picked up or get delivered.

if he is picking up then i do not need to capture his address. In my current implementation I created two required paramaters named "OrderType" and "deliveryAddress"

so the question is how do i skip deliveryAddress capture if value of OrderType is pickup ?

Please note that I am using fb messenger as a channel so the value of orderType would be coming from FB.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to put this as a comment but do not have 50 reps required for commenting. 
Hence putting this as an answer though it is just a workaround and not the right solution.

I had faced a similar issue and achieved it by giving a default value to the required parameter. And then comparing in my fulfillment logic whether the value is default or else it would have been via user input. Not the right way but just a work around if no one replies with the right solution.